# jquery: if-statement for var in dropdown-menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, if-statement, var

I applied a replacement for a dropdown-menu and the jQuery replacement stays empty because the preselected value of the select-option-form is undefined (the values are generated dynamically). When I click the replacement and choose an option it works as it should. Here is the excerpt of the replacement code I think it is responsible for the error:

```
function createDropDownSF(){
  var searchForm_type = $("#searchForm_type");
  var selected = searchForm_type.find("option[selected]");
  var options = $("option", searchForm_type);
```

Therefore I tried to extend the function with this code, to make the function use the first option available when there is no selected value, but it doesn't work:

```
if (selected.is("undefined")) {
    searchForm_type.find("option")[0];
}
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: `searchForm_type.find("option")[0];` this just finds the first option, it doesn't do anything with it. Are you using some sort of plugin to replace the dropdown?

Comment: yes, it is a replacement plugin that I found in the net. this code above is added to the plugin as a workaround for the preselected-value-problem. But as you describe it, I should add a line to use  the found option for the display?

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to get a list off al the options that are selected and check if the length > 0.

```
 $("select option:selected").length > 0
```

Then you can use JQuery to select the first option.

```
$('select option').first().attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean it that way?

```
function createDropDownSF(){
  var searchForm_type = $("#searchForm_type");
  var selected = searchForm_type.find("option[selected]");
        $("select option:selected").length > 0;
        $('select option').first().attr('selected', true);
  var options = $("option", searchForm_type);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="test">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option selected="selected">3</option>
<option>4</option>
```

```
$(function () {

    if ($("#test option:selected").length > 0) {
        // something is selected
        alert("selected");
    } else {
        // nothing is selected
        $('#test option').first().attr('selected', true);
    }
});
```

I don't know how to set the select that is doesn't have a value selected, but this code should work.